# My RESTUL WCF doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, wcf

I have the followings:

```
In Competitions.svc:

<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="MySite_WebSite.Pages.Client.CompetitionsSVC" CodeBehind="Competitions.svc.cs" %>
```

In ICompetitions.cs :

```
namespace MySite_WebSite.Pages.Client
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "ICompetitions" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract(Name="CompetitionsSVC")]
    public interface ICompetitions
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(
            Method = "GET"
            , RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
            , ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
            , UriTemplate = "DoWork"
            , BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped
        )]
        Dictionary<DateTime, List<Competitions.Entry>> DoWork();
    }
}
```

In Competitions.svc.cs :

```
namespace MySite_WebSite.Pages.Client
{
    [DataContract]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
    public class CompetitionsSVC : ICompetitions
    {
        #region ICompetitions Members

        public Dictionary<DateTime, List<Competitions.Entry>> DoWork()
        {
            var c = new Competitions();

            return c.GetMonthlyEntries(new Competitions.ParamGetMonthlyEntries()
            {
                Start = DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-1)
                , End = DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(2)
                , UserLang = "fr-BE"
                , ActiveLang = "fr-BE"
                , IsExternal = false
            });
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

In Web.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MySite_WebSite.WS.WCF.SubsetMID">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="MySite_WebSite.WS.WCF.ISubsetMID" />

        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
      <service name="MySite_WebSite.Pages.Client.CompetitionsSVC">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior"
                  contract="MySite_WebSite.Pages.Client.ICompetitions" />

        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IServiceWCallBack" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IHandleSubset">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment
        multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"
        aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
    />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

When I enter the url

```
localhost2/MySite_WebSite/Pages/Client/Competitions.svc/DoWork
```

, it doesn't work.
I have a breakpoint at the begining of the method, and I can see the method gets called twice, yet it doesn't return anything (I don't even think it send any HTTP code backs).

What did I do wrong?

**Additional notes:**

`Entry` is actually a "base class".

```
    public class EntryCompetition : Entry
    public class EntryEvent : Entry
```

In my code the dictionary actually contains `EntryCompetition` and `EntryEvent` instances.

Comment: I added "Additional notes"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting your code that definitely helps.  But i think you're going to need to show a little more work, and some more concrete results on how your project is failing.  But so as not to leave you helpless. I recommend looking at Fiddler

http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

It allows you to create Http requests and to see the responses inside of it's console.  it is useful for seeing specifically what http response code your endpoint is returning, and allows you to modify your request through the composer window.

another helpful tip, would be to step all the way through your code, so you can point us to exactly what line is failing or what values are being set before your method completes.

Without more information, my best guess is you're code is throwing and most likely swallowing an exception.  Or your methods or calls are setting null values that don't return the values you expect.  Please reply once you've setup some further tests and updated your question if you are still having issues.

Comment: The result is like the server is not responding at all. No 404 or what so ever. For instance, when I make the request with firefox, it ends up appending www. and .com to "localhost2".

Comment: [Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes. (Note: I set browser.fixup.alternate.enabled to false to prevent +www. +.com)

Comment: Maybe i misunderstood, but can you confirm that you are getting into your code when you make a call.  It sounded like you could debug and hit break points.

Comment: if that's true can you check what value you would be returning you could change your code to this in your endpoint method

`var ret = c.GetMonthlyEntries(new Competitions.ParamGetMonthlyEntries()
            {
                Start = DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-1)
                , End = DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(2)
                , UserLang = "fr-BE"
                , ActiveLang = "fr-BE"
                , IsExternal = false
            });
            return ret;`

Comment: The value is what I expect it to be. But, (I'm still trying to figure things out) if I try to return an empty dictionnary, I get the expected output {"DoWorkResult":[]}. So the problem comes from how .Net serialize the object (those objects aren't "DataContract objects").

Comment: Dictionaries should work by default, but you may want to consider adding Data Contract attributes on your Entry Type, also if Entry has any interfaces defined in it's property that could be causing issues.

Comment: a good test might be to change the List of Entry to a List of String, or some other primitive type, and then see if it's able to output a populated Dictionary with primitive types, that would let you know whether it's your complex type or not.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the problem. I use a custom piece o code to serialize the dictionnary into a JSON string and I don't use DateTime objects as keys anymore.